# urllib.request fails on urlopen of unicode string

Tags: python, unicode

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen, urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def save_picture(self, word):
    search_string = "https://www.google.nl/search?q={}&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:m".format(word)

    request = Request(search_string, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    raw_website = urlopen(request).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_website, "html.parser")
    image = soup.find("img").get("src")

    urlretrieve(image, "{}.jpg".format(word))
```

I wrote the function above to save the first tumbnail image from Google Images. The problem however is that it fails when I input a non ansii word, say: mañana

The error message originates from within the urllib module. I'm using python 3.6

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\users\xxx\Desktop\script.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()   File "c:\users\xxx\Desktop\script.py", line 16, in main
    save_picture("mañana")   File "c:\users\xxx\Desktop\script.py", line 8, in save_picture
    raw_website = urlopen(request).read()   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1117, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii')) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**edit:** after reading up I discovered there are several libraries for this task, urllib, urllib2 and requests (and also via pip : urllib3). Am I getting this error because I'm using a depreciated library?

**edit2:** added full traceback

Comment: Post the full traceback so we have context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import mimetypes
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def save_picture(self, word):
    search_string = "https://www.google.nl/search?q={}&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:m".format(word)
    response = requests.get(search_string, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    #find the tumbnail for first hit
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    image_location = soup.find("img").get("src")

    # download image
    image = requests.get(image_location)
    content_type = image.headers.get('content-type')
    ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type)

    with open(f"{word}{ext}", 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in image.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

I rewrote the function using requests, which handles the unicode strings as expected. Saving the file is a bit more verbose however